# Page-distance between labels

Tags: sectioning, page-numbering

I'd like to instrument my sections with the length of the section (in pages, lines, ect).

**Section Title** --> **Section Title (12 pages)**

Instead of statically generating this information and adding it; I'd like to have a dynamic solution;

```
\section{Section Title (\pagedistance{label1,label2} pages)}
\pagedistancelabel{label1}
...
...
\section{Section Title (\pagedistance{label2, label3} pages)}
\pagedistancelabel{label2}
...
...
```

Does a package exists for this currently?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct command for the page distance but it's possible to use the `refcount` package by Heiko Oberdiek (One of the TeX Gurus here on TeX.SX ;-)).

The problem with references is that they could be anything (numbers, links etc.) and the commands `\ref` and `\pageref` are not expandable. However, the `\getpagerefnumber{label}` command returns a pure number and is expandable.

I've defined a `\pagedistance{label1}{label2}` command, which regard the the first label as the reference point (= i.e. the zero level) and subtracts the ref count number of the second label. If the difference is negative, then `label1` is on an earlier page than `label2`.

The command does not check whether the labels do exist.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{refcount}
\newcounter{pagediff}

\newcommand{\pagedistance}[2]{%
\setcounter{pagediff}{\getpagerefnumber{#1}}%
\addtocounter{pagediff}{-\getpagerefnumber{#2}}%
\number\value{pagediff}%
}%
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\section{A: \protect\pagedistance{sectionB}{sectionA} pages ahead} \label{sectionA}

\blindtext[50]

\section{B: \protect\pagedistance{sectionA}{sectionB} pages backwards} \label{sectionB}
\blindtext[20]

\section{C: \protect\pagedistance{sectionA}{sectionC} pages backwards} \label{sectionC}


\end{document}
```

Some improved version (please note, that `\pagedistance` is not expandable any longer)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{refcount}

\newcounter{pagediff}


\NewDocumentCommand{\pagedistance}{smm}{%
  \setcounter{pagediff}{\numexpr\getpagerefnumber{#2} -\getpagerefnumber{#3}}%
  \IfBooleanF{#1}{%
    \number\value{pagediff}%
  }%
}

\newcommand{\Pagedistance}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \pagedistance*{#1}{#2}% The starred version doesn't print the number, it stores only. 
  \def\x{\number\value{pagediff}}
  \ifnumgreater{\x}{0}{%
    \x\ pages ahead%
  }{%
    \ifnumless{\x}{0}{%
      \x\ pages backward%
    }{%
      On the same page%
    }%
  }%
  \endgroup
}




\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\section{A: \protect\Pagedistance{sectionB}{sectionA}} \label{sectionA}

\blindtext[4]

\section{B: \protect\Pagedistance{sectionA}{sectionA}} \label{sectionB}

\section{C: \protect\Pagedistance{sectionA}{sectionC}} \label{sectionC}


\end{document}
```

[image]